# How to run script (one using qt libraries) on server from client?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, server, client

I need to execute some code on server side when some conditions on client side are met. What is the best way to do that? Is it possible to run .exe file from client program, or can I make some kind of listener on special port, which will run my executables when call is on? Client and server running under Windows both.

Comment: You should first figure out which protocol you want to use to start remote processes  and only _then_ ask the question how to implement it.

Comment: To be honest, I dont even know which options I have. So I guess it is part of my question :(

Comment: Start by investigating [PSExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) and SSH (either the server [built into Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), or a commercial offering such as [Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) or [CopSSH](https://itefix.net/copssh))